# Using CapsLock to switch the keyboard language layout on Windows-7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout, input-languages, capslock

Currently I am using [Recaps](http://www.gooli.org/blog/recaps/) for switching between keyboard layouts. But I am looking for a replacement, because it is a little buggy and not updated for years. Do you know any replacement?

Comment: Any particular OS, or will you accept an answer for Haiku?

Comment: Recaps is a Windows app, so it is either that or Plan 9

Comment: Is it alright for `Alt` + `Shift` to still be assigned to language switching? If so, AutoHotkey could be used to send an `Alt` + `Shift` on `CapsLock`.

Comment: @Reza Your AHK code is wrong. `+` is the `Shift` modifier, it must come **before** `{Raw}` or normal keys. Try: `Send, +{LAlt}`

Comment: @iglvzx It did not work.

Comment: What do you mean by `not so stable yet`?

Comment: @Bob It stop working in  win 7 suddenly, also you have set language each time you restart windows

Comment: I rolled back laste edit as I felt it changed question *entirely*.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen please undo your rollback.

Comment: IMO, "I am using product x to .." and "how to use key x to .." are *entirely* different questions. I suggest you edit your question *yourself* to something like "Is there a key combination to switch between keyboard layouts?".

Comment: Or "does windows offer a way to switch between KB layouts using key combo". Something like that. I feel what I did was the right thing to do. The edit has to solve issue with the question, not change the question intent entirely.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Windows, you can set Windows to use Grave Accent (<kbd>`</kbd>)  for switching between languages or keyboard layouts via a single key press.

If your windows is set to change keyboard layout by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> you can use the following AutoHotKey script (I strongly recommend using http://www.autohotkey.com/) to map them to <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, normal <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> will be achieved by <kbd>Shif</kbd>+<kbd>CapsLock</kbd>

```
SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff
+CapsLock::CapsLock

CapsLock::Send, {Ctrl down}{Shift down}{Shift up}{Ctrl up}{Ctrl up}
return
```

Comment: http://l.autohotkey.net/ is down :(

Comment: @turbanoff Updated.

Comment: Second `{Ctrl up}`? Why?

Comment: I was forced to use windows at work after a long time, and can't even imagine how easy things were in Ubuntu and how difficult these things are here on Windows. For things as trivial as a keyboard shortcut you have to install an separate program.

Comment: ⊙﹏⊙ I wish I had AHK in ubuntu to easily create my shortcut!

Comment: A little off topic, but in Windows you don't always need to install a program for keyboard shortcuts. To start programs, you can add keyboard shortcuts to the desktop shortcuts, from their properties. Also, AHK is just a nice tool to programmatically create macros, including, but not limited to creating keyboard shortcuts. Also, with linux you have the benefit of choosing a distro that has all the features that you want preinstalled. Windows is a one size fits all and im glad that they don't add ALL the bloat that some people might not need.

Comment: @PHPst on ubuntu caps lock could be enabled to switch layaout in settings without any scripts.

Comment: @PHPst Fantastic. Thank You much!

Comment: @GennadyG pleasure

Comment: This hotkey is no longer reliable in Windows 11. It often doesn't switch the language.

Comment: How can I modify this script to  run it natively in version 2? Now it asks me to download AHK v1 when I start this script

Answer (score 41):

Following [@Bob](https://superuser.com/questions/429930/using-capslock-to-switch-the-keyboard-language-layout#comment494242_429930)'s suggestion to use [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com), the following script will simulate <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> when you press <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>:

```
CapsLock::Send, {Alt Down}{Shift Down}{Shift Up}{Alt Up}
```

*Windows can be a little stubborn when it comes to keyboard shortcuts only consisting of modifiers, but the above technique works.*

Comment: Wonderful, works like a charm! Thanks for this.

Comment: What about Caps Lock for 1st layout and Shift+CapsLock for 2nd layout, any idea?

Comment: It worked very nice, but sometimes the keyboard-layout switching menu remained open. I found an even better alternative: Use the settings to make the grave (`) key switch layouts, and then use this AutoHotkey script:

CapsLock:: Send, {vkC0sc029}
SC029:: Send, {Alt down}{Numpad9}{Numpad6}{Alt up}

(I used https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys to find the key code of the key. Then, when actually pressing the key, it uses alt-96, which types the character.)

Comment: Thanks! This helped me. The above script is for AutoHotKey v1. Since there's a v2 already, here's the same script compatible with v2:

`CapsLock::Send("{Alt Down}{Shift Down}{Shift Up}{Alt Up}")`.

Answer (score 22):

Use [lswitch](https://haali.net/winutils/).

> Use any key to switch input languages, usage: `lswitch [keycode]`.
> Keycode is optional and defaults to context menu key. Another good
> candidate is a `CapsLock` key with a keycode of `20`.

Cheers!

Comment: Simplest solution.

Comment: This works for English, German and/or Russian keyboard layouts or input languages as well. The only thing that reliably worked for me for decades already in any Windows version. Add a shortcut it to C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup with target "lswitch.exe 20" (no quotes) to run all the time. Grave Accent doesn't work for e.g. German layout.

Comment: This is work great! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 7):

Punto Switcher can do this! http://punto.yandex.ru/win/

Basically it allows you to switch keyboard layout automatically, based on what you are typing. But it also can switch keyboard layouts on Caps Lock or many other keys. If don't like automatic switching you can turn it off in settings.

Comment: Dose it have an English version?

Comment: Sorry, it seems that it's Russian only. Probably because it's main function is keyboard layout auto-switch (rus-en). Anyway, my answer can help Russian users.

Comment: too much functional for this task in this app.

Comment: Still smaller then AHK though

Answer (score 3):

Around a year ago I switched from ReCaps to [keyla](http://code.google.com/p/keyla/) and I am pretty much happy with it.

Comment: Skype 7.23 hangs when switching language via Caps Lock in Windows 10.

Comment: Keyla site is die.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Capslang](http://flydom.ru/capslang/): simply download suitable exe and put it in folder

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

(to make it launch automatically when system starts)

Comment: wow, and it's open source! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I made it using [PowerPro](http://powerpro.cresadu.com/) tool (as if it is constantly loaded already for other stuff)
And now I achieve language change by tapping and CAPSLOCK via long press.

Answer (score 0):

You can easely (by changing first two lines to:

```
$~CapsLock::LangSwitch(1)
$~CapsLock up::LangSwitch(2)
```

) modify wOxxOm's [Keyboard layout switcher](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/24666-keyboard-layout-switcher/) for using Win+Space instead of right control. And it will work no matter which hotkeys are set up for switching layout in Windows (default is Alt+Shift, I'm using Ctrl+Shift).

Because of non-ahk-native switching (script uses WinAPI), whole script is rather bulky, so I didn't paste it inline. In case of autohotkey.com inaccessibility, here it is: http://pastebin.com/RayAw1VP

(again, all credits go to wOxxOm, source script is there: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/24666-keyboard-layout-switcher/)

P.S. That script is quite old, and has hardcoded byte-offsets, so I'm not sure if it will work with 64-bit Autohotkey.exe or in 64-bit Windows. I only have 32-bit at hand.

P.P.S. This answer is nearly duplicate to [another](https://superuser.com/a/845654/131936) but questions are also nearly similar.