# Way to switch keyboard layout with a hotkey without crashing Skype on Windows 10

Tags: skype, keyboard-layout, autohotkey, windows-10, winapi

Prior to Windows 10 I was using something similar to Autohotkey scripts mentioned [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/546843/how-do-i-send-a-keyboard-layout-switch-event-with-autohotkey-in-windows-7). After upgrading to Windows 10, PostMessage to a Skype chat window causes Skype to freeze.

Is here another way to switch keyboard layouts? I have 3 layouts and want to be able to enable any of them with Ctrl, Alt and Shift keys (single presses), and my script still works outside of the Skype.

Here is an example of the script that triggers the issue:

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input

ru := DllCall("LoadKeyboardLayout", "Str", "00000419", "Int", 1)
~RCtrl & F1::return
~RCtrl::PostMessage 0x50, 0, %en%,, A
```

With this script running, RCtrl instantly freezes the Skype. Do I need to send something else?

Comment: It's known problem of Skype. Check here: http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Skype-v-7-7-freezes-on-Windows-10-after-pressing-keyboard-local/td-p/4066735

Answer (score 1):

Pretty annoying Skype problem with hang on keyboard layout switch.
For user workaround is to use `[Win]+[Space]` combination.