# What does a capital A (without an underscore) do in AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

What does a capital `A` (without an underscore) do in AutoHotKey?

For example, the following script ([taken from here](https://superuser.com/questions/546843/how-do-i-send-a-keyboard-layout-switch-event-with-autohotkey-in-windows-7)) changes the current language to Russian, and it uses a capital `A`:

```
ru := DllCall("LoadKeyboardLayout", "Str", "00000419", "Int", 1)
PostMessage 0x50, 0, %ru%,, A
```

P.S. all `A_` variables are listed [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm), but `A` isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A** as a command or function parameter **means the active window**.

> If WinTitle is the letter A and the other 3 window parameters
>   (WinText, ExcludeTitle and ExcludeText) are blank or omitted, [the
>   active window](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#ActiveWindow) will be used.

See also [WinActive-->Remarks](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActive.htm#Remarks_8).