# How do I switch between languages on Windows 10 like I do in OS X?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, input-languages

OS X has this really nice feature when you have 3+ keyboard input sources (languages) and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> you switch between only two of them.

If you want to switch to another (third) language you just hold <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and press <kbd>Space</kbd> to choose from the list of input sources available.

How can I have similar functionality on Windows 10? I have 3 input sources and looping through them to get to the one I need is really annoying.

Comment: What do you mean by “looping through them”? I’m not familiar with the OS X function, but could you perhaps explain if and why Win+Space isn’t appropriate?

Comment: For example you have EN, FR and DE. You on FR now. To get to EN you need to press Win+Space twice. In OS X you have only 2 active inputs (EN, FR) despite how many inputs you use. To make input active you hold CMD and press SPACE. You get a list of all languages (EN, FR, DE) and selecting it make this language active.

Comment: You must really use it to understand how convenient it is.

Comment: So, perhaps you should further enlighten us about the OS X function, because Cmd + Space is the Spotlight shortcut. Also, what’s the difference between the shortcut in your paragraphs 1 and 2? Sounds like Windows to me.

Comment: How many input sources do you use? Perhaps one...

Comment: Do you mean switching between the 2 recently-used languages? Too bad this is not available in Windows.

Comment: Do you want to do this *without* selecting the language with the mouse? You can easily set it up so you click a keyboard icon in the Taskbar, and it lists languages, and you just click the one you want to type in.

Comment: 1) Yes! Basically you switch around 2 recently-used languages and when needed, you change one of them. 2) I can change language HUNDREDS times a day, so it's definitely not an option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One can assign in Windows 10 a keyboard shortcut to a language :

1. Go to *Control Panel -> Clock, Language, and Region -> Language -> Advanced settings*.
2. Under *Switching input methods*, click *Change language bar hot keys*,
   then click on your language, and finally on *Change Key Sequence*.
3. This will display a dialog where you can assign a shortcut key to that language:

[image]

Since the above shortcut keys are quite limited,
it is possible by using for example [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) to change this to any other
keyboard combination. Once you learn AutoHotkey, it will be easy to reproduce the exact behavior of OSX (one can also ask for help on their forum).

Many AutoHotkey scripts can be found on the Internet and one can tailor them
to fit any need.

The following example script aims at improving the functioning of
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> as a toggle between the English and Russian keyboards for the current window :

```
; This should be replaced by whatever your native language is. See 
; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
; for the language identifiers list.
ru := DllCall("LoadKeyboardLayout", "Str", "00000419", "Int", 1)
en := DllCall("LoadKeyboardLayout", "Str", "00000409", "Int", 1)

!Shift::
w := DllCall("GetForegroundWindow")
pid := DllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", "UInt", w, "Ptr", 0)
l := DllCall("GetKeyboardLayout", "UInt", pid)
if (l = en)
{
    PostMessage 0x50, 0, %ru%,, A
}
else
{
    PostMessage 0x50, 0, %en%,, A
}
```

Here are some threads offering scripts for changing the keyboard layout
with various functionality :

- [Keyboard layout switcher](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/24666-keyboard-layout-switcher/)
- [Keyboard layout switcher for many layouts](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/70019-keyboard-layout-switcher-for-many-layouts/)
- [Using CapsLock to switch the keyboard language layout](https://superuser.com/questions/429930/sing-capslock-to-switch-the-keyboard-language-layout)

Here are some free products that do that as well :

- [keyla](https://code.google.com/archive/p/keyla/wikis/en_Main.wiki) - Can define keyboard shortcuts or use a taskbar icon
- [Recaps](http://www.gooli.org/blog/recaps/) - Uses CapsLock to switch the keyboard language

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of this solution. I even tried it for a while. Didn't like it much. Because every time you need to think to what language do you want to switch. Also try pressing 'CTRL + 1'. No so easy for fingers, isn't it? But maybe it's only me ;)

Comment: Using for example [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/), you can change this to any other keyboard combination. Once you learn AutoHotkey, it will be easy to reproduce the exact behavior of OSX (one can also ask for help on their forum).

Comment: Thank you, @harrymc ! This script is almost as good as OS X solution. I use 'ALT + Shift' to switch between two mostly used languages and 'Win + Space' to switch to the third one.

Comment: Proposed solution does not answer the question. The sweet thing on macOS is two switch between two _most recent_ languages, but solution is about switching between two _mostly used_ languages. This tiny thing makes a huge difference!

Comment: Look for the language ID in `regedit`. `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload`

Answer (score 7):

If you want the exact behavior as in macOS, without having to configure, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to switch between the two recently used languages, like what you get from <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

To switch to other input methods, like when you hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> twice, just use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: Wow! It's exactly what I was looking for! I didn't know about `Ctrl`+`Win`+`Space`

Answer (score 2):

## How to switch languages in Windows 10 (almost) like in OS X, Android, IPhone

There is (almost perfect) solution for this issue in **Windows 7**,
which is possible to implement in **Windows 10** with few additional steps.

## Background

The solution is based on the fact that there're two distinct entities
in Windows: *Input Language* and *Keyboard Layout*.

By default *<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>* loops through configured *Input Languages*
and it is *Input Language* which people usually add when they require
additional languages in their systems.

But.

1. It is possible to alter behavior of *<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>* (or *<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>*
   if you prefer) to loop through *Keyboard Layouts* and not to change
   *Input Language*.
2. It is possible to specify different keyboard shortcut
   for every *Input Language* (as it is also described in one of other answers to this question)
3. Most importantly it is possible to add unrelated *Keyboard Layout* to an *Input Language* (even layout with different script), for example Hebrew Layout to English Language. This step is a bit tricky in **Windows 10**, but doable.

Finally you'll end up having several different *Input Languages*,
for each of which you'll have separate keyboard shortcut, but
once you choose *Input Language* you'll be able to use regular *<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>*
which will loop between defined *Keyboard Layouts* "inside" of the *Input Language*.

## Configuration in Windows 10

For simplicity, let's assume that you want to use 3 languages: English, Russian and Hebrew. Upon completing the steps below you'll have three modes
of operation:

- English mode, used by default, selected with *<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>* and *<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>* (or *<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>*) looping between English and Russian
- Hebrew mode, selected with *<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>* and with *<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>* (or *<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>*) looping between English and Hebrew
- Russian mode, selected with *<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>*  and with *<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>* (or *<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>*) looping between English and Russian

Steps to configure.

1. *Ctrl-Esc* (which opens Start Menu) - or Windows Button in the left bottom corner of the screen
2. Type *Language* (which should bring up Language item from Control Panel), press Enter
3. Depending on your vendor you might have English and your regional language. Assuming you have only English, add Russian and Hebrew with *Add a language button*
4. Every language comes with default *Input Method*, which corresponds to the language. Now we will add "unrelated" *Input Method* to each *Input Language*:

   1. Download [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/keyboardlayouts.aspx)
   2. *File -> Load Existing Keyboard.*
   3. Choose the layout which you want to add (let's start with Russian Layout for English Input Language)
   4. *Project -> Properties*
   5. Modify *Language* to match *Input Language* for which you want this keyboard layout to be available. It would be English (United States) in our case.
   6. Press *OK*. You might need to modify *Description* slightly if you get "Keyboard description is identical" error message. Just add some suffix.
   7. Open the Project menu and choose *Build DLL and Setup Package*. Ignore warning, agree to open directory where Windows Installer package was built.
   8. Run *setup.exe*, which installs your *Keyboard Layout* for the chosen *Input Language*
   9. If you reopen (close and open once again) *Language* screen (from step 2) and choose *Options* for *English (United States)* language, you should see **two** input methods now: *US* and *Unavailable input method*
   10. Repeat steps 4.1-4.9 for all the needed keyboard layouts (for the example that we're discussing, we would need two more repetitions: load English keyboard set Language to Russian in *Project -> Properties* and build it, load English keyboard again, set Language to Hebrew in *Project -> Properties* and build it).
5. Upon successful completion of previous steps you should have *Unavailable input method* on the *Options* screen for every language that you used as the target language in step 4.5.
6. Last step is to configure keyboard shortcuts. Open *Language* screen (steps 1-2)

   1. Choose *Advanced settings* (on the left pane of *Language* screen)
   2. Choose *Change language bar hot keys*
   3. Choose *Between input languages* (left mouse click) and press *Change Key Sequence* button
   4. Choose *Not Assigned* in the *Switch Input Language* pane
   5. Choose *Left Alt + Shift* (or the one you prefer) in *Switch Keyboard Layout* pane
   6. Confirm (OK).
   7. Choose *To English (United States) - US* (left mouse click), press *Change Key Sequence* button, check *Enable Key Sequence*, choose *Ctrl* and *1* (or any other preferrable), confirm
   8. Choose *To Hebrew (Israel) - Hebrew (Standard)* (left mouse click), press *Change Key Sequence* button, check *Enable Key Sequence*, choose *Ctrl* and *2* (or any other preferrable), confirm
   9. Choose *To Russian (Russia) - Russian* (left mouse click), press *Change Key Sequence* button, check *Enable Key Sequence*, choose *Ctrl* and *3* (or any other preferrable), confirm
7. Reboot (yes, keyboard shortcuts are quite buggy in Windows, once you change them, you'll need to reboot so that they're registered correctly).

## Configuration in Windows 7

Configuring the same use case in Windows 7 is simpler and doesn't require
downloading additional tools.

1. *Ctrl-Esc* (which opens Start Menu) - or Windows Button in the left bottom corner of the screen
2. Type *Region and Language* (which should bring up Language item from Control Panel), press Enter
3. *Keyboards and Languages* tab -> *Change keyboards*
4. Choose *Add* button and search for *English (United States)* section
5. Click *+* (plus sign) which open *Keybord* section
6. Open it and click *Show More...* item, which will complement the list with all the different languages, find *Russian* in this list and check it (make sure you selected Russian inside of Keyboard inside of English (United States) list.
7. After confirming you should have two Keyboards under *EN English (United States)*: US and Russian.
8. Click Add, search for *Hebrew (Israel)* and select *Hebrew*, *Show more...*, *United States-International* (which will be available only after choosing *Show more*), confirm
9. Click Add, search for *Russian (Russia)* and select *Russia*, *Show more...*, *US* (which will be available only after choosing *Show more*), confirm
10. Go to *Advanced Key Settings* tab
11. Choose *Between input languages* (left mouse click)
12. Choose *Change Key Sequence* button
13. Set *Switch Input Language* to *None*, *Switch Keyboard Layout* to *Left Alt + Shift* (or *Ctrl + Shift*), confirm
14. *To English (United States) - US* -> *Change Key Sequence* -> *Enable Key Sequence*, set to *<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>*, confirm
15. *To Hebrew (Israel) - United States-International* -> *Change Key Sequence* -> *Enable Key Sequence*, set to *<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>*, confirm
16. *To Russian (Russia) - US* -> *Change Key Sequence* -> *Enable Key Sequence*, set to *<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>*, confirm
17. Confirm (OK).
18. Reboot.

## Notes

There's one peculiarity: in some programs you might get garbled characters, unless you switch to the right *Input Language* (for example, if you get garbled Russian input, use *<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>* to switch to Russian keyboard layout). But it happens quite rarely and only in some unusual circumstances (for most of Windows users), doesn't really bother me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
; AutoHotkey Script
#SPACE::
  Send ^#{SPACE}
Return

; ♥
; macOS-like input language change algorithm
; Just use WIN + SPACE as normal
; Hold the WIN then tap SPACE to loop


; Test environment
; OS Version  : Windows 10 1803
; AHK Version : 1.1.30.01


; Title  : default setting should be like this
; Date   : 4/8/2019
; Author : who cares
```

Comment: Works amazing! Is there any way to do this for Alt + Shift?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> to iterate throught the defined languages (and it loops ;) ).

Comment: That's exactly how I do it now :(

Answer (score 0):

I caught your meaning.You mean IME (Input Method).you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to set defeat IME,and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> to move to next IME .

Answer (score 0):

The direct registry setting to disable the keyboard layout toggle hotkeys is:

```
reg add "HKCU\Keyboard Layout\Toggle" /v "Layout Hotkey" /d 3
```

You might also want

```
reg add "HKCU\Keyboard Layout\Toggle" /v "Language Hotkey" /d 3
reg add "HKCU\Keyboard Layout\Toggle" /v "Hotkey" /d 3
```

And for new users, try this (in an elevated prompt):

```
reg load HKEY_USERS\temp "%USERPROFILE%\..\Default\NTUSER.DAT"
reg add "HKEY_USERS\temp\Keyboard Layout\Toggle" /v "Layout Hotkey" /d 3
reg unload HKEY_USERS\temp
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! On this Q&A site we try to provide [good answers](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) to questions people post. Part of writing a good answer is including explanation of what the listed steps do, this is not present in your answer. Please edit your answer to explain what each of the registry edits does, so people can decide whether or not they want to perform the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Type in the search bar of the start menu **Control Panel** -> Click **Language** -> Click **Advanced settings** -> Click **Change language bar hot keys** -> Click **Change Key Sequence**

Answer (score 0):

For anyone like myself who found themselves here by searching for the default key command for toggling keyboards, the default in Windows is Left <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>`Shift`</kbd> is useful if you only have two input methods, but if you have more than two you'll need to use the *left* and *right* <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>`Shift`</kbd> combo:

- left <kbd>Alt</kbd> + left <kbd>`Shift`</kbd>: switching input methods from the top to the bottom
- right <kbd>Alt</kbd> + right <kbd>`Shift`</kbd>: switching input methods from the bottom to the top

Then if you switch from input method 1 to 2 using left <kbd>Alt</kbd> + left <kbd>`Shift`</kbd>, you can go back by using the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> + right <kbd>`Shift`</kbd>.

These are default hotkeys in Windows 10 & 11, no other settings are needed.

> For nerds: if you use Alt + Shift to switch between the input methods, the actual order of switching depends on the last key you hit.
>
> - <kbd>L Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R Shift</kbd> will also do bottom -> top
> - <kbd>R Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L Shift</kbd> will also do top -> bottom
>
> Samething for <kbd>L Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R Alt</kbd> and <kbd>R Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L Alt</kbd>.