# Is there a way to map caps lock to switch keyboard layout on MS-Windows 10?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

pretty much the title. I searched a bit, but all I could find is the standard settings. I come from Linux, where this thing is built in, but I expect there is some tool I can use to achieve this.

Answer (score 8):

First you may read info on how to set default shortcuts:
[Shortcuts for switching keyboard layout](https://superuser.com/questions/958901/set-shortcuts-to-change-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10)

On Windows 10 there is a new feature: you can switch with <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (just test and see)

Here is an approach with <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> for Windows 7:
[Capslock to switch layout](https://superuser.com/questions/429930/using-capslock-to-switch-the-keyboard-language-layout?noredirect=1&lq=1)
Similar AHK script works on Windows 10 as well.

To summarize tested and working Autohotkey approaches:

###Option 1. Bind <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to simulate <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>

First make sure that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> is the default key combo.
Use this AHK script:

```
capslock::
    send {Lalt down}{Shift}{Lalt up}
return
```

###Option 2. Bind <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to the new <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> combo

I'd prefer this because it gives good visual feedback when switching.

Here is the script to bind it to <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>:

```
sel := 0

#if (sel=0)
capslock::
    send {lwin down}{Space}
    sel := 1
return 
#if

capslock up::
    send {lwin up}
    sel := 0
return
```

Comment: I had issue with these solutions on Win10 where real caps lock state was changing even if AutoHotkey had captured key presses. Turns out, caps lock state should be explicitly switched off (taken from [similar question](https://superuser.com/a/431302/967860)):
`SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff`,`+CapsLock::CapsLock`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean switching between the standard qwerty,azerty etc. keyboard layouts and not between any custom mapping presets. If you have those different keyboards installed for your selected language in the Region & Language settings you should be able to quickly switch between them with `win + space` shortcut.

Comment: No, I actually mean switching between languages. I prefer the use of a single key over dual key, and I have almost no use for the capslock key to justify keeping it there.