# Use only one button to switch between keyboard languages

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, language

I am trying to find a way to assign just **one keyboard button** to switch between different keyboard languages. I cannot find a third-party software to help me resolve this issue. I am working a lot with three languages and it is tedious to switch between them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, or any combination whatsoever. I am working on Lenovo Y520 (Windows 10 Pro).

Comment: Would a single click instead of a single button/key?

Comment: It has to be a button so I can do speed-texting, for example: I am willing to give my **F2** button this functionality

Comment: Use autohotkey and search for the required script

Comment: Search for a script that combines the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> to a particular key which can be mapped on the F2 key.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1340640/456981

Comment: Guys, I can not thank you enough for the info. Autohotkey works like a charm , but I will try @MikhailV 's idea - for Win-7 it works perfectly, today I will check it out with Win-10

Comment: @NewJavaEnthusiast: I'm looking for solution of similar problem. Did you found some solution for the Windows 10? If YES, can post/share you solution the answer, please?